# Passing a list to SQL each row call Groovy

Tags: sql, grails, groovy

I am currently rendering a list of sql rows from a database using:

```
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def list = []
def index = 0
params.mrnaIds.each { mrnaName ->
   sql.eachRow ("select value from patient_mrna where mrna_id=$mrnaId") { row ->
      list[index] = row.value
      index++
   }
}
render list
```

However I would like to avoid assigning the values to a list before rendering them.

The variable `params.mrnaIds` is coming from a multi select input, so it could either be a single string or a string array containing ids. Is there a way to iterate through these ids inside the eachRow method?

I would like to be able to execute something like:

```
render sql.eachRow ("select value from patient_mrna where mrna_id=?", params.mrnaIds) { row ->
   list[index] = row.value
   index++
}
```

But I'm not completely sure that there is a way to call eachRow with this functionality. If there is not, is there some other way to render the results without storing them in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can `render` each row:

```
sql.eachRow( someQuery, someParams ){ row ->
  render row as JSON
}
```

Comment: Works great! Although since I was trying to print out float values I can't call as JSON on them unless I pass them to a map.

Answer (score 1):

There is `rows()` to return a list instead ok working with it (like `eachRow()` is used for).  It also shares all the different arguments. E.g.:

```
render sql.rows("select value from patient_mrna where mrna_id=?", params).collect{ it.value }
```

Comment: This return a not serializable exception

Comment: @janDro Are you using the `collect`?

Comment: The first one, although I think it would be for both

Comment: @janDro I have changed the anwer, as the first one only was an example.  You can not serialize the Growresult-thingy there and have to use the collect.

Comment: This only works for me if there is only one value in the params.mrnaIds in my case. Otherwise I get Invalid value "2" for parameter "parameterIndex"

Comment: @janDro Well then use `in` in your SQL.  Instead of a collect you can also use a `collectEntries` to build a map, which most likely is serializeable.  Yet this diverges from the original question.